# JQuery Dialog Help

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-dialog

So I have a button on my UI that calls this Javascript function:

```
function OpenHistory(transactionId, spanThatWasClicked)
    {   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("ViewHistory", "Indications") %>",
            data : { transactionId : transactionId },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#history").html(data);
                $("#history").dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: "Valuation History",
                    width: 850,
                    height: 500,
                    autoOpen: true,
                    buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

The `#history` it's setting just looks like this on the page: `<div id="history"></div>`

First time I click it -- makes the AJAX call, opens the dialog, everything looks perfect.

*Close the dialog*

Second time I click it -- nothing happens. It makes the AJAX calls and everything, but no dialog appears on the screen.

*Refresh the page*

It goes back to working again on the FIRST click only, just like last time.

Is this some dialog weirdness?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the success code to this:

```
      success: function(data) {
            $("#history").html(data)
             .dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: "Valuation History",
                width: 850,
                height: 500,
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
            }).dialog('open');
        }
```

This way it will make **sure** its open with the `dialog('open')` call

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the dialog was already created once the `autoOpen` doesn't trigger on subsequent calls.  Try adding `$("#history").dialog("open")` in the ajax call and see if that helps.
You could add some optimization to make sure you don't call the original dialog creation code twice (some kind of a boolean variable)

Answer (score 0):

You should only call this once to create the dialog

```
           $("#history").dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: "Valuation History",
                width: 850,
                height: 500,
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: { "Close": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
            });
```

To open the dialog call `$("#history").dialog("open");`

I recommend creating your dialogs when the page is first loaded with `autoOpen: false` and opening them as needed